# Cannot configure Email-ext

Tags: jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I can no longer  add an email-ext post build step to my jenkins jobs.

This worked before,  but the I upgraded to jenkins 2.7.1 and the email-ext plugin 2.44.

Now, when I add an post build step to a job and try to save the modified job, I will be taken to a login page and  this page will lead to an error and the new step will not be saved.

Frank

Comment: Please add if you have any errors in the Jenkins log. Without that, it is a bit difficult to be able to tell what's wrong, and you'll just get the usual "Have you tried rebooting it?" kind of answers... Also, if you found a solution yourself, don't hesitate to add it as an answer and accept it too...

Answer (score 0):

1. One solution is to downgrade your jenkins to earlier working version.
2. Try uninstall/reinstall of email plugin.
3. If you are OK with the New version and not willing to downgrade and wanted email as a post build step, follow the below steps.

Steps:

1. Login to the server where you have installed jenkins and traverse to the that jobs config.xml path.
2. add the email section to the job's config.xml [You can refer to other existing job's config.xml which contains email section as a post build and use the same in this job, paste those lines in your job's config.xml]
3. Save you changes.
4. Now come back to your jenkins GUI and goto manage jenkins section.
5. Click on "Reload Configuration from Disk", This will reload your changes from server.
6. You will now be able to find the changes saved.
7. Another way is to update the job config.xml from jenkins command line.
   search for jenkins-cli.jar and you will find a route.